# Creating a recursive function in Javascript / jQuery based on an option grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I'm trying to generate a list of images needed for options from a list of selections.

I'm able to do it like this:

```
var imagesNeeded = [];
$('.woodStyles .optionLabel').each(function(index) {
    var woodStyle = $(this).html();
    $('.grainStyles').find('.optionLabel').each(function(index) {
        var grainStyle = $(this).html();
        imagesNeeded.push(grainStyle+woodStyle);
    });
});
console.log(imagesNeeded);
```

As you can see the code above is recursive in nature, what I'm trying to do is create an array like this:

`var options = ['grainStyles', 'woodStyles'];`

And do the same thing as the code above but using a recursive function so that I can generate a list of needed images from an unlimited number of options.

I've tried wrapping my head around this in so many directions and I can't figure it out.

---

So if I created an array like this: `var options = ['grainStyles', 'woodStyles', 'finishTypes'];`

The recursive function would need to do the same thing as this code:

```
var imagesNeeded = [];
$('.woodStyles .optionLabel').each(function(index) {
    var woodStyle = $(this).html();
    $('.grainStyles').find('.optionLabel').each(function(index) {
        var grainStyle = $(this).html();
        $('.finishTypes').find('.optionLabel').each(function(index) {
            var finishType = $(this).html();
            imagesNeeded.push(grainStyle+woodStyle+finishType);
        });
    });
});
console.log(imagesNeeded);
```

Comment: It doesn't look particularly recursive to me, which leads me to believe I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you give an example of html that you would want this to work against?

Comment: Say for example I need to add another option to check against, so the new array is: `var options = ['grainStyles', 'woodStyles', 'finishStyles'];` I'll edit the code above to show what this will look like

Comment: @SteveCampbell added an example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a number of lists of options, and you want to generate a list of all permutations of options.

This could be done recursively, as in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Ly1ezpk/):

```
function getImagesNeeded(options) {
  if(options.length == 0) return [""];
  var thisClass = options[0];
  var imagesNeeded = [];
  $('.' + thisClass + ' .optionLabel').each(function(index) {
    var value = $(this).html();
    $.each(getImagesNeeded(options.slice(1)), function(i, suffix) {
      imagesNeeded.push(value + suffix);
    });
  });
  return imagesNeeded;
}
```

There are other ways to do it though. For example, [without recursion](https://jsfiddle.net/57xewvbc/):

```
function getImagesNeeded(options) {
  var imagesNeeded = [""];
  $.each(options, function(i, optionName) {
    var newImagesNeeded = [];
    $.each(imagesNeeded, function(i, oldImageName) {
      $('.' + optionName + ' .optionLabel').each(function(i, label) {
        newImagesNeeded.push(oldImageName + label.innerHTML);
      });
    });
    imagesNeeded = newImagesNeeded;
  });
  return imagesNeeded;
}
```